# Why aren't the votes separately being shown in our own questions timelines anymore?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes, timeline, score

I have seen before, that I could see votes on my own questions separately (e.g., upvotes and downvotes).

But now I can only see the **net** votes score without separation to upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: That's a [privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) (which you get at 1000 reputation, so not sure how you were able to see it before). In your reputation history, you *can* see up- and downvotes separately.

Comment: I don't talk about splitting the score. I'm talking about the timeline. I can see the up-votes and down-votes separately on the timelines of questions of **other** users; but I can't see it in my own questions.

Comment: Funny.  Can you give us a screenshot of your own/another's timeline?  I'm just fine.

Comment: Seeing up-votes and down-votes in the timeline is tied to that privilege.